# Загрузить и переключить версию php в Linux

Tags: php, linux

Подскажите, можно ли загрузить PHP 5.6 и переключиться на него с версии 7.2 не удаляя последнюю? Если да, то подскажите как это всё сделать. Оболочка Ubuntu

Comment: оболочка линукс какая?

Comment: Ubuntu, вроде бы 16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ sudo apt-get install php5.6

$ which php5.6
```

Должен отобразиться путь до php5.6 что-то типа `/usr/bin/local/php5.6`, копируем её

```
$ sudo ln -s ставим_сюда /usr/bin/php

$ php -v
```

*Версия 7.2 должна быть доступна по команде `php7.2` - проверим так: `$ php7.2 -v`*

Comment: Между ними можно будет переключаться?

Comment: `sudo ln -s ставим_сюда /usr/bin/php` таким образом

Comment: $ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/local/php5.6 /usr/bin/php. Правильно я понял?